# How to deal with questions regarding Windows 10 icon troubles

Tags: discussion, windows-10

So the day has finally come and it seems there are even more people having problems with this "Windows 10 icon" now.

Three of the newest questions are related to this icon: [1](https://superuser.com/questions/947038/windows-10-icon-dissappeared), [2](https://superuser.com/questions/947042/windows-10-icon-missing-in-spite-of-following-advice-from-previous-threads), [3](https://superuser.com/questions/947043/windows-10-icon-not-showing-up). I have seen quite a few posts saying they have tried everything previously mentioned and it still doesn't work for them. Usually this type of question would be marked as duplicate.

**Now there is a new breed of question**. People are reporting that they used to have the icon, but now it is missing. I've seen this on other sites/forums as well. Is this an actual problem or just part of the Windows 10 upgrading phase? I'm not sure if the icon is even relevant anymore as the iso is available. Perhaps the icon is being removed on purpose. Does anyone have information on this or ways to answer these questions?

Comment: What is the question exactly?  The icon is suppose to disappear.  This problem isn't a duplicate of the existing icon question, technically, it isn't a problem.

Comment: @Ramhound "The icon is suppose to disappear" do you have a source or explanation for this? If so then you could write an answer to one of the questions and we can close the others as dupes ...

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing. Is there any source/information regarding the disappearing?

Comment: @DavidPostill - Its either suppose to disappear or the website it displays itself is causing the process to silently crash.

Comment: @Ramhound "the website it displays itself" does not make any sense. Again "do you have a source or explanation for this?" Your first comment seems to be guesswork :/

Comment: @DavidPostill - The tool in question had before July 29th displayed a website.  A machine that had the icon at 1:30PM EST on July 29th then after a couple restarts I noticed it was gone by 6PM EST.  I conclude only one of two things happened.  1) It i was suppose to go away since Microsoft is doing a phased roll out. 2) The website the tool displays is causing it to actually silently crash before the status icon can be shown.

Comment: @Cfinley The phased rollout I know about, as do most people. Still no specific information about whether the icon is _supposed_ to disappear at some point.

Comment: @Cfinley - While I am right about the phase roll out.  I am extrapolating the reason the icon is not being shown to some devices.  All I know is the icon was visible on my PC on the 29th, then only after I performed a restart, did I noticed it was gone that night.  The icon was only used to "download Windows 10 ahead of the release date" aka "reserve".  Going forward everyone will be prompted via Windows Update about the upgrade.

Answer (score 8):

An answer just because there isn't one.

The proper way to deal with any quantity of repeated questions with the **same question** in them is to mark them as duplicates.
Marking as a dupe requires a few regular users to mark that (agree), or a mod can also mark it.

To mark as duplicates it would be really good if there was a well written properly working answer (accept not nessiarily required) that is tested and actually does cover the situation for the majority of users.

The questions that fit into the one specific issue are then marked as dupes. IMO pointing not to the first one, or the last , but pointing to one with a great and complete answer

Many new windows 10 upgrade questions , some that will be obsolete, and some that will live much longer, need the right well written answers, and for the dupes to be marked to those good answers.
 Some already have good answers, or answers that just need updating.
 Many repeat questions for windows 10 upgrading can already be marked as dupes

Anyone with some rep can assist in doing that. Anyone making the great answers to point to could aquire rep for the great answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess we will never know why the icons disappeared but it doesn't seem important now as there is a tool provided by Microsoft. I didn't mark as duplicate as I felt the icon disappearing was different than not having it in the first place but they have marked by others.

Comment: I also feel that you are completely correct that there can be 2 seperate ideas in this, and many other situations (some where it is wrongly marked as a dupe).  To me the 2 are different indeed.